# Is it possible to recursively require all files in a directory in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, recursion

I am working on an API that needs to load all of the .rb files in its current directory and all subdirectories.  Currently, I am entering a new require statement for each file that I add but I would like to make it where I only have to place the file in one of the subdirectories and have it automatically added.

Is there a standard command to do this?

Comment: Just a note: REQUIRING a set of possibly unknown files is dangerous and also can lead to errors. Let's say I put a file called die.rb with an exit statement in it (sorry, no actual code, I've never used Ruby), as soon as it is loaded, the program ends.  Or what if the user deletes a file? The functions provided by that file would not be loaded.  

If you just want to disregard the security issue, including the files and checking to make sure they were loaded (by calling some sort of check function), might work, but again, no Ruby experience.

Comment: Why would you put `die.rb` in your project? If the project is already old and has collected junk I would agree this is dangerous. For a newish project, however, it's a sensible move that makes it hard for somebody to accidentally add `die.rb` to the codebase (it would fail on load/bugs made clear sooner rather than later)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In this case its loading all the files under the lib directory:

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load(f) }
```

Comment: why do you use `load` and not `require`?

Comment: You can use both, but require is usually passed a library name, with no extension, rather than a file name.

Comment: but `require`, doesn't mind if you pass in the extension, so in my opinion it is preferable

Comment: If you use `require`, the file will be treated as a source file and loaded as a library. Using `load` causes the file to be run as a script and will prevent any local variables in the loaded file from being imported into the current environment.  Ruby will also let you re-import a file with `load` but not with `require`.  Either syntax can be used here, just make sure it is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: "Libraries" are just files afterall.  When you have `require 'bundler'`, Ruby finds the file `bundler.rb` in the `lib` directory of the bundler gem and runs the code in that file.

Answer (score 6):

```
require "find"

Find.find(folder) do |file|
  next if File.extname(file) != ".rb"
  puts "loading #{file}"
  load(file)
end
```

This will recursively load each `.rb` file.

Answer (score 4):

like Miguel Fonseca said, but in ruby >= 2 you can do :

```
    Dir[File.expand_path "lib/**/*.rb"].each{|f| require_relative(f)}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the gem [require_all](https://github.com/jarmo/require_all) all the time, and it gets the job done with the following pattern in your requires:

```
require 'require_all'
require_all './lib/exceptions/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rLoad(dir)
    Dir.entries(dir).each {|f|
        next if f=='.' or f=='..'
        if File.directory?(f)
            rInclude(f)
        else
            load(f) if File.fnmatch('*.rb', f)
        end
    }
end
```

This should recursively `load` all .rb files in the directory specified by `dir`.  For example, `rLoad Dir.pwd` would work on the current working directory.

Be careful doing this, though.  This does a depth-first search and if there are any conflicting definitions in your Ruby scripts, they may be resolved in some non-obvious manner (alphabetical by folder/file name I believe).

Comment: Why aren't you matching directly against `f` in your load call?

Comment: If you are referring to the statement `File.fnmatch('*.rb', f)`, the statement returns true if the filename `f` matches the pattern `*.rb`.  This ensures that we are only `load`-ing ruby scripts and not any other files that might happen to be in the folder.  Note that you may have to add another condition if you also have some scripts that use the .rbw extension.

Comment: Yes. But you could have used `load(f) if f =~/\.rb/`. I was referring to why you're using fnmatch over the builtin regex support.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  When I wrote the above code I happened to be working on something else that was using the fnmatch method so that line was pretty much a copy/paste.  I suppose `~/\.rb$/` regex would work as well (added the `$` to prevent matching files like "script.rb.bak").

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this [gem](http://github.com/mlightner/require_directory). It is quite small so you can actually re-use the code instead of installing the whole gem.