# How do I make a Ruby script to move .mp3 files to iTunes folder?

Tags: ruby, shell

In order to get my music into iTunes, I have to find its location and then I have to dig into my files to find my iTunes folder and copy/paste it into my iTunes folder.

What I want is a Ruby script that will scan the folder that it is in for files that end in `.mp3` and then move those files into my iTunes folder.

I know how to move the files into iTunes if I know the name of the file, however, how can I find only the `.mp3` files to my iTunes folder. I just need some direction into what I can use to only select files ending with `.mp3`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849699/is-it-possible-to-recursively-require-all-files-in-a-directory-in-ruby

Comment: It's probably something like `Dir['**/*.mp3']` check [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'find'
require 'fileutils'
Find.find('/') do |f|
  FileUtils.mv(f, "ABSOLUTE PATH TO ITUNESFOLDER") if f.match(/\.mp3\Z/)
end
```

This will probably take a while as it will scan the entire directory tree of it's start point, in this case '/' (the entire file system). Maybe start in your home directory instead of '/'

Answer (score 2):

You can use this recursive method to find files in many directories and move them to your itunes folder.

```
def ls_R(dirname)
   Dir.foreach(dirname) do |dir|
      dirpath = dirname + '/' + dir
      if File.directory?(dirpath)
        if dir != '.' && dir != '..'
          ls_R(dirpath)
        end
      else
        FileUtils.mv(dirpath, "PATH_TO_ITUNESFOLDER") if dirpath.match(/\.mp3\Z/)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: The implementation of Find.find is recursive, it also supports multiple arguments: Find.find('/path1', '/path2', '/path3/, /'weeeeeeee').

Answer (score 0):

A remark to both solutions offered above:
there is a "add automatically to itunes" folder which you should target
for this type of action.

`....../iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/`

This allows for a better way to get your tracks in iTunes.